# Trinket translation problem

Tags: translation

Could you translate me this phrase or sentence please. No translating app is helping me and I have no one who knows Chinese.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It means "Certificate of Handsome Guy" or "Handsome Guy Certificate".

Comment: Does it mean anything special in Chinese culture? Is it a saying? Or is it how usually said in China and in which situation?

Comment: Nope, it's not a significant thing in Chinese culture. It's not even a saying. I think this thing is a really nice gift for a guy friend LOL.